# Add data to Dataframe with pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, insert

I want to add a result from a simulation model to an existing dataframe at a specific position with the dataframe.

Based on a dataframe and model for linear regression I am calculating a value. This value must be added to the input dataframe used for the linear regression. I am using pandas insert functions which brings the following error:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pwd2X.png)

Comment: Looks like `y_heute_10` has two dimensions (i.e., nested brackets), but only holds one value. Try `df.insert(2, 'Stunde_10', y_heute_10[0])`

Answer (score 0):

Thank you very much for you help. It worked with:

```
X_heute_10 = df2.insert(4, 'Stunde_10', y_heute_10[0,0])
```